# Soak or Ferment pulses?

Tags: fermentation, soaking, pulses

What is the science behind soaking pulses? Any way to measure if soaking is complete/done well?

What is fermenting of pulses do? What is the science behind it?

Is it better to soak or ferment pulses? Are they comparable or totally different?

I just know about soaking green gram & chick peas before cooking. I was told that if its starting to froth on the top, its too much time and will effect the pulses. I just heard of fermenting soybeans and there to properly ferment, you have to wait till it froths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I soak beans before cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/434/why-should-i-soak-beans-before-cooking)

Comment: No, I understand soaking. I am curious about fermentation & how it compares against soaking.

Comment: They're completely different things. That are unrelated to each other. It's like asking how frying pans compare to kangaroos.